# Problem with adding Unity.Entities to a project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity 2020.3.0f1 LTS project. I added Entities, Mathematics, Hybrid Rendered packages to test DOTS. After successful adding, I do not see Unity.Entities namespace in the Visual Studio for Mac (8.9.10) when I type Unity namespace. In the newly created project in the same 2020.3.0.f1 LTS after adding the same packages I see Unity.Entities namespace. It looks like there is some problem with adding Entities package. I tried to remove and add package again, did not help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, i tried a lot of stuff but was resolved as soon as i regenerated the csfiles,

[image: external tools]

**Edit >Preferences> Regenerate project files** that after the installation of the package.